# Menu Items added to Visual Studio are disabled

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012

I was following the instructions at https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html to integrate some common SVN commands to my visual studio IDE. Here are the steps I followed

1. Selected Tools | External Tools and added commands for SVN Log, Blame and Diff.
2. These commands show up in the Tools Menu and are working as expected
3. Next, selected Tools | Customize | Commands | Context Menu. Under the Context Menu drop down, chose the Editor Context Menus | Code Window
4. Using Add Command, added the 3 commands. These options now show up in the code window context menu but are disabled.

I am not sure what additional steps need to be performed to get these menu items to show up enabled. I had this working till recently but lost it when I reset my settings. Appreciate any help in this regard
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g66Bb.png)

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use VisualSVN?

Comment: None except for not having heard about it. Will give it a try.. thanks for the tip